# Button in iOS app for selecting an image or taking a picture

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to implement a button to my swift app to open photo lib or camera to save a photo as a "data" datatype. My project does not use a storyboard so everything is implemented code wise and IBA Action will not work. My code is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct TaskInsertView: View {

    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TaskInsertViewModel

    var body: some View {
        @State var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
        @State var selectedPhotosData: [Data] = []
        
        VStack {
            //date arrived section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Date Arrived  :")
                DatePicker("", selection: $viewModel.startDate)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            
            //first and last name section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("First and Last Name : ")
                TextField("First and Last Name", text: $viewModel.taskfirstandlast)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            .padding()
            
            //phone number section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Phone Number : ")
                TextField("Phone Number", text: $viewModel.taskphonenum)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            .padding()
            
            //description section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Description : ")
                TextField("Description", text: $viewModel.taskdescription)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            .padding()
            
            //blast section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Blast : ")
                TextField("Blast", text: $viewModel.taskblast)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            .padding()
            
            //prime section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Prime : ")
                TextField("Prime", text: $viewModel.taskprime)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            .padding()
            
            //color section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Color : ")
                TextField("Color", text: $viewModel.taskcolor)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            .padding()

            //image section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button(action: ){
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            .padding()

            //button click
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.onAddButtonClick()
                }) {
                    Text("Add")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                }
                .background(.blue)
                .cornerRadius(.infinity)
                .padding()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to implement PhotosPicker but could not use it because of the datatype. I tried to find a way to translate the datatype to data but was unable to do it. If you have any suggestions on how to change the datatype I can add to the question what I did before this. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onChange with a PhotosPicker to load & convert it to data like so:

```
//image section
HStack(spacing: 20) {
    Text("Image")
    PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedImage, label: {
        Text("Picker")
    })
}
.onChange(of: selectedImage) { img in
    Task {
        if let data = try? await img?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
            viewModel.taskimage = data
        }
    }
}

//image display
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: viewModel.taskimage) ?? UIImage())
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

Tested and working in Xcode 15 Beta 2 on an iOS 17 Simulator, let me know if it needs a revision for older versions.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 14 with iOS 16 minimum and I'm getting an error at the ".onChange" line titled... "Contextual closure type '([PhotosPickerItem]) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body" I tried changing how "selectedImage" was declared in the beginning with no luck :/ I'm guessing it's something to do with the Xcode version?

Comment: So, I got that issue cleared but since I don't know much on chaining, I have a new error on the task line..."Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type'[PhotosPickerItem]'"

Comment: Yes for older versions you would do: .onChange(of selectedImage) { image in, instead of _, image in. I will update my original answer accordingly. However I swapped to Xcode 14 and am unable to reproduce your other issue. Please ensure selectedImage a single optional value, defined with “@State var selectedImage: PhotosPickerItem?”